# How to add extra data frames into VNC communication?

Tags: video-streaming, addition, frame, vnc

Does anyone knows how to add extra data frame along with video frames in vnc communication. Both client and server will be handled by me. And also how to do encode and decode that extra data frame at both the sides.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best reference I've found on the RFB (VNC) protocol is: http://tigervnc.org/cgi-bin/rfbproto

You have a couple of general directions.

If you don't mind extending the protocol, then you can just add new message types to your protocol (since you control both ends). See the [clientcuttext](http://tigervnc.org/cgi-bin/rfbproto#clientcuttext) and [servercuttext](http://tigervnc.org/cgi-bin/rfbproto#servercuttext) as examples of existing messages for sending an arbitrary amount of data in either direction. The disadvantage is that if your client or server is connected to be a different client or server then this will cause a fatal error.

Another option is to extend an existing message in a backwards compatible way. For example, you could send client to server message by sending mouse events that are outside the viewport (and then sending a final mouse event that is back inside at the real location). You could send server to client messages by sending frame buffer updates that are outside the viewport. That won't be displayed by normal clients.

Comment: hi kanaka, thanks you too for fast respone.Can I have  any secure means also in the communication. Client will be running on QT and server will be on Android.

Comment: There are a couple of encryption modes that are standard parts of the VNC protocol such as VeNCrypt and SASL (which are upgrades mid-stream). You can also SSL encrypt the entire stream from the beginning using SSL. People often do this with the stunnel command, but if you have access to an SSL library on both sides then you can do it yourself. The painful part of this type of encryption, though, is always the key management part.

Comment: Ok, So I can use clientcuttext and servercuttext for passing extra data, along with encryption, my client and server will always remain fix ?

Comment: Can you rephrase your last question? I'm not sure what you mean by "remain fix".

Comment: ok, that means client and server will remain same always. Only one client and server is there. No other client or server will be added in communication.

Comment: Sure, if you control the client and server than you can send whatever you want using the clipboard messages. If you still want to support regular clipboard messages, you probably want the first byte of the clipboard message to be a control byte that indicates what sort of messages you are sending.

Comment: thanks for your fast reponse once again. I am using [fbvnc](http://pocketworkstation.org/fbvnc.html) for QT and for android [android-vnc-server](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-server/). I am new on VNC , so can please refere me some code snippet or any tutorial, that shows how to use Clipboard messages.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'watermark's. You can set every Xth frame to have data. Every pixel would be used to store a bit of data. Record every pixel at every X-1th frame, and for every Xth frame ignore any actual change in the server's video feed but if you want the bit to be 1, make that pixel darker, and if you want it to be 0, keep the pixel the same. On a 1024 by 768 pixel display, you can potentially store 786kb of data every X frames with this method. Make sure to not compress the stream for the frames that will store data, through.

If you don't need 786kb, only do it for the top half of the screen, you'll save some bandwidth, and you'll get half of 786kb to use as data.

You should be able to implement most if not all encryption fine. You can do lots of obfuscation too. Maybe every 3rd bit is random and useless. Maybe if the 1st bit is 1, flip everything. Etc etc.

Comment: Hi gladoscc, After reading your answer I have realized that I have not asked my question in proper way. I have edited my question.Apologies for that mistake. I need to add only data frames in vnc communication along with video frames. your answer is some what like stenography that was right according to previous question.

Comment: I have looked at the VNC protocol. There is no official standard on sending custom data, so you'll need to create a non-standard event. 

I have found this pdf document which describes the VNC protocol in great detail along with all standard (and some unofficial) events:

www.realvnc.com/docs/rfbproto.pdf

It's impossible to offer exact "what to do" tutorial-style advice, as I don't even know what language you are going to code it in!

If you don't have a clue on how to implement this, sorry but you should do something easier first.

Please don't be put off by my tone in this post! :)

Comment: Hi gladoscc, My vnc server is on android and client is running on Embedded QT. Till yet we are able to see server on client and can control events. Hope now you get tad more idea about the situation.